# Passing string from Parent to Child via @Input on Angular 16

Tags: angular

Somehow I just can't pass `someErrorString` from Parent to  **page-error** childcomponent. The UI of page-error just shows nothing while I expect `Hi!`. Am I doing something wrong?

**Parent**

UI:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="currentPage === 'error'">
  <page-error
    [someErrorString]="someErrorString"
    (errorReceived)="onErrorReceived($event)"
  />
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="currentPage === 'code'">
  <page-code
    (errorReceived)="onErrorReceived($event)"
  />
</ng-container>
```

Logic:

```
someErrorString: string

onErrorReceived(someErrorString: string) {
  this.someErrorString = someErrorString;
  const nextUrl = this.someErrorString ? 'error' : 'code';
  this.router.navigate(['prefix', 'page', nextUrl]);
}
```

**page-error**

UI:

```html
<p>Message: {{ someErrorString }}</p>
<button (click)="onRetry()">Retry</button>
```

Logic:

```
@Input()
someErrorString: string;

@Output()
errorReceived = new EventEmitter<string | null>();

onRetry() {
  this.errorReceived.emit(null);
}
```

**page-code**

UI:

```html
<button (click)="onClick()">Just say Hi</button>
```

Logic:

```
@Input()
someErrorString: string;

@Output()
errorReceived = new EventEmitter<string | null>();

onClick() {
  this.errorReceived.emit('Hi!');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in parent component, there's no `currentPage` property.

I tried to reproduce the error, so I created a new angular project and when I added the `currentPage` property, it worked just fine.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PageErrorComponent } from '../page-error/page-error.component';
import { PageCodeComponent } from '../page-code/page-code.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [PageErrorComponent, PageCodeComponent],
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrl: './parent.component.scss'
})
export class ParentComponent {

  someErrorString!: string;
  currentPage: 'error' | 'code' = 'code';

  onErrorReceived(someErrorString: string | null) {
    if (someErrorString) {
      this.someErrorString = someErrorString;
      const nextUrl = this.someErrorString ? 'error' : 'code';
      // this.router.navigate(['prefix', 'page', nextUrl]);
      this.currentPage = nextUrl;
    }
  }
}
```

PS: I'm using Angular 17, but it's the same thing.